# Need to Transfer 390 GB of Data from Linux Server to Windows Machine

Tags: linux, windows, samba, rsync, webdav

We want to transfer 300+ GB of data from a Linux Server to a WIndows Server.

Can we use rsync (and if so, how would we?) to copy the files from the linux server to the windows file share?

Or should we use WEBDAV, what are all of our options? We are looking for the most efficient manner in doing this -

They are a bunch of small individual files (roughly 2 million files) -

Answer (score 1):

You can use rsync if you install cygwin on your windows machine.

Comment: Or [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

### Not enough information

1. Are they physically next to each other?
2. Do they have fast internet connections?
3. Is the data continually changing, ie. are the machines live?
4. Does the Windows machine have a Unix environment configured, eg. cygwin?
5. Do you have root/administrative access to both systems?
6. Is there a firewall between the two servers?
7. Is the data of a sensitive nature, ie. is security paramount?
8. Is the Linux machine running a web server, eg. to present the file via HTTP?
9. Do you have remote access to the Windows machine?
10. Did you make any effort at all to think of anything before posting this question?

My advice, carrier pigeon, it was proven faster than ADSL http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8248056.stm

You've not mentioned any important details (ie. That it needs to be done without downtime etc.), so the most basic solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods of doing this.

I generally run a rsync daemon on the Windows server using Cygwin that shares out the /cygdrive folder. From there the files can be easily copied over and the paths line up with the Windows box.

Note that there are some limitations to the Cygwin implementation of rsync but based on the file / size listing provided you should be within tolerances.